# Can I share beyondCompare setting between machines?

Tags: beyondcompare4

On my linux machine beyondCompare's settings are stored in `~/.config/bcompare`.  I would like to share these between my different machines.  Can I:

- Create a git repo in `~/repos/bcompareSettings`
- Move the contents of `~/.config/bcompare` to `~/repos/bcompareSettings`
- Symlink `~/.config/bcompare` to `~/repos/bcompareSettings`
- Push/Pull the git repo periodically and share it among different machines?

Comment: Settings are mostly XML. The recommended method to share settings is with the Tools > Export Settings and Tools > Import Settings commands. Copying the config folders outside of Beyond Compare also works to transfer settings, so the git method you propose might work, although I've never tried it.